# Conectar aplicación en Android Studio a un servidor externo con certificado de seguridad

Tags: java, android, app

Tengo una app android que usa JSON para leer y escribir en una BD. En mi localhost funciona a las mil maravillas, mi problema es que al cambiar la url a la de un servidor (con IP) la app no se conecta. Sin embargo, al escribir la URL directo en el browser del celular, si se ejecuta la pagina. ¿Será problema del certificado de seguridad? Cuando escribo la url en el browser indica que no es un sitio seguro, sin embargo, ejecuta la página de todas formas.

Desde ya gracias y quedo atento a sus respuestas.

En la clase java del Activity donde hago la validación de usuario tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (cd.isConnected()) {

        final String username = etusuario.getText().toString();
        final String password = etpassword.getText().toString();

        Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success) {
                        String nombre = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                        String apellido = jsonResponse.getString("surname");
                        int brigada = jsonResponse.getInt("brigada");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Logon.this, Opciones.class);
                        intent.putExtra("nombre", nombre);
                        intent.putExtra("apellido", apellido);
                        intent.putExtra("usuario", username);
                        intent.putExtra("brigada", brigada);

                        Logon.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Logon.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Error en usuario o password")
                                .setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null)
                                .create().show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error JSON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        LogonRequest logonRequest = new LogonRequest(username, password, respoListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Logon.this);
        queue.add(logonRequest);
```

el logonRequest es la clase donde se especifica la URL y se llama al servicio web que validará al usuario:

```
public class LogonRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGON_REQUEST_URL= Constant.RUTA_WEB + "appLogon.php";//"http://192.168.0.15/ConnBD_Android/appLogon.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;
    public LogonRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, LOGON_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params=new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);


    }


@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

la variable Constant.RUTA_WEB contiene la primera parte de la URL:

```
public class Constant {

    //public static final String RUTA_WEB    = "http://192.168.17.74/ConnBD_Android/";
    public static final String RUTA_WEB    = "https://10.10.12.94/obras/CONNBD_ANDROID/";

}
```

Esto ya lo probe con un servidor local y funciona perfecto, sin embargo cuando uso la URL del servidor del cliente, no me puedo conectar.

Comment: Hola, Te sugiero que veas como preguntar en el sitio y agregues tu codigo. **muy importante leer [ask]**. Por otro lado estas seguro que tu WS acepta conexiones ? algunos servidores exigen conexiones seguras, uso de sentencias preparadas, etc ..

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. ¿el código lo agrego en esta parte de comentarios o creo una nueva pregunta? en caso que el servidor requiera conexioens seguras, como establesco una conexión segura?

Comment: y lo otro, esta directiva de conexión segura, sería del servidor web o del sistema operativo de la máquina.?

Comment: Tú código lo debes agregar en tu misma pregunta, en el botón editar. Las reglas de seguridad se hacen en el servicio web y así mismo puedes validar ciertos aspectos en Android

Comment: Solucioné el problema. Como el servidor era interno, no tenía sentido que tuviera certificado de seguridad. Lo que se hizo fue quitar el certificado de seguridad y configurar el webserver(apache) para no trabajar ocn conexión segura. Cabe mencionar que el certificado que tenía el servidor estaba vencido.